# Change font in a single paragraph

Tags: fonts

> **Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document)

How is it possible to use a new font for just a single section of a document and switch back to the original font after that paragraph?

I have:

```
\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont
```

Which works fine for part way through a document changing the font. But how do I revert back?

Comment: @krlmlr In what way does the accepted answer here or the linked duplicate *not* answer the question, such that it would need to be reopened?

Comment: @AlanMunn: The accepted answer here answers the question. However, the answer to this question is buried deeply in the longish answer(s) to the alleged duplicate,

Comment: @AlanMunn: By "reopen" I just vote for removing the [duplicate] status of the question. Please feel free to undo if you think this is inappropriate.

Comment: @krlmlr Since this is a *very* common question, having a link to a definitive answer is a useful thing, (and what prompted creating that question in the first place). Since the accepted answer here has plenty of votes (and is accepted) I'm sure plenty of people who encounter this version of the question won't get bogged down in the more detailed linked answer.  But removing it altogether I don't think is a good idea.

Comment: @krlmlr I rolled back your edit but added in your clarification.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Now I see what you mean. IMO, the link to the definitive answer should be added to your accepted answer, to the bottom, and the "duplicate" status of the question should be removed -> "reopen".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can always restrict the scope of font changing commands by enclosing the paragraph in braces

```
{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont ... }
```

If this is something you will be doing a lot, it would make more sense to turn it into a proper environment:

```
\newenvironment{ppl}{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont}{\par}
```

Then you use it like any other environment:

```
\begin{ppl}
Some text in the new font.
\end{ppl}
```

Comment: A good idea to end these sorts of environment with \par, I think. Especially necessary, although not in this case, if the paragraph settings will change (e.g., with \small).

Answer (score 6):

Use the `fontspec` package,

Then you can define new commands to select font families as `\newfontfamily\cmd[font features(optional)]{Font_Name}` and apply it by `\NewFontName{SOME TEXT!}` or `{\NewFontName SOME TEXT}`

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\unicodefont{Lucida Grande}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
A legacy \TeX\ font. {\unicodefont A unicode font.}
\end{document}
```

You can use the `\newenvironment` command to define a new environment by using this new font.

Comment: Note that this requires the use of XeLaTeX, not pdfLaTeX. (And strictly speaking it answers the question of how to change a font, not how to restrict the scope of the change.)

Comment: OP did not mandate the use of PdfLaTeX, and for those who use IDE like software for LaTeX work can just switch to XeLaTeX using some easy option. This is much more neat compared to the methods that require finding the LaTeX friendly font family names, which actually look nothing like the human readable versions of them. But `fontspec` would just accept the human readable version, which is really convenient.