# Using a font for selected text

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document)

How can I use the `chancery` font for only selected text instead of the whole document?

Comment: Exact duplicate of this question? [Change font in a single paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11539/2693)

Comment: @Alan: It is definitely similar. I interpreted this question as being more about which obscure combination of characters makes up the font family name for Chancery. In this case, it is pzc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can change the font family using `\fontfamily`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\chancery{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
Normal Computer Modern. {\chancery Chancery.} Back to CM.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Regis: If you are using XeLaTeX see also [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11539/change-font-in-a-single-paragraph/11552#11552) which shows a similar but simpler approach using `fontspec`.

Comment: This answer got me wondering.. Is there some kind of manual or document that contains a list of all these font families? I know the, but that's only for document wide font changes. 

I'd like to have a list of existing fonts with their shorthand names (like `pzc` in your example).

Comment: @romeovs: We were actually just contemplating this on meta. I'm unaware of such a document. I just looked in `chancery.sty` to figure out the answer to this question. I think you should ask a question asking for exactly that list. What I'd like is a list of fonts, the packages to use for them, and the font family names for them as well.

Comment: @romeovs for the standard fonts, the document `psnfss2e.pdf` (`texdoc psnfss` should find it).  For all of the possible fonts there is the online [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).  For XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX the available fonts are any fonts installed in your system.

Comment: The above code works but not when I change pzc to something else?