# Is there a list available for all TeX fonts?

Tags: fonts, berry

I was reading trough the answer to [Using a font for selected text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12821/using-a-font-for-selected-text/12823#12823). In the answer, the code makes use of the `\fontfamily`command. This command takes one argument: the shorthand name of a font. E.g. in the question mentioned above the `chancery` font is called `pzc`.

It got me wondering if there is a list available that sums up all these shorthands?

I know [Tex Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/allfonts.html) sums up the packages that change fonts, but this only document wide and doesn't show the shorthands.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Such shortcuts are mainly useful for you if you have the font installed. Such lists are on your system. If you use pdfTeX, take a look into `pdftex.map`. You could find it by

```
kpsewhich pdftex.map
```

at the command prompt, or use any search feature of your system. It shows the font mappings.

There are ways you could get the concrete information you need. I would list all installed fonts by

```
updmap-sys --listmaps
```

On my system it lists nearly 200 lines of font maps, such as

```
Map fourier.map
Map kpfonts.map
Map libertine.map
Map lm.map
...
```

so I know which fonts are installed. I posted this earlier [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/what-fonts-are-installed-on-my-box/2308#2308).

To see the respective shortcuts, I would look into those files. Since I can find them using `kpsewhich`, I type

```
gedit `kpsewhich kpfonts.map`
```

using gedit or any other editor. So I find the shortcuts inside: `jkpmnc` etc.

Often I take the quick way and look into the `sty` file to hopefully find the correct shortcut. Again, I use `kpsewhich` like

```
gedit `kpsewhich aurical.sty`
```

---

Remark, for an explanation and an outlook: `kpsewhich` works also on Windows. `gedit` is a GNOME editor, mainly used on Linux, such as Debian and Ubuntu. The backticks in the command lines evaluate the command and give the output to `gedit`. Because of command line features, piping, grepping, replacing with regexp and many more I like to use TeX on Linux. Here, I look for font names on my complete system, filtering for Charter fonts, cutting the output a bit by `sed`, the stream editor:

```
updmap-sys --listmaps | sed 's/^.* \(.*\)$/\1/' | xargs kpsewhich |       xargs grep -i charter | sed 's/^.*:\(.*\)<.*$/\1/' | sed 's/<.*$//'
```

which returns:

```
bchb8y CharterBT-Bold "TeXnANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont" 
bchbo8y  CharterBT-Bold "0.194 SlantFont TeXnANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont" 
bchbi8y CharterBT-BoldItalic "TeXnANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont" 
bchr8y CharterBT-Roman "TeXnANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont" 
bchro8y  CharterBT-Roman "0.194 SlantFont TeXnANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont" 
bchri8y CharterBT-Italic "TeXnANSIEncoding ReEncodeFont" 
bchrc8a CharterBT-SmallCap 
bchbc8a CharterBT-BoldSmallCap 
bchr8v VnBitstreamCharter " T5Encoding ReEncodeFont " 
bchri8v VnCharterBT-Italic " T5Encoding ReEncodeFont " 
bchro8v VnBitstreamCharter " 0.194 SlantFont T5Encoding ReEncodeFont " 
bchb8v VnCharterBT-Bold " T5Encoding ReEncodeFont " 
bchbi8v VnCharterBT-BoldItalic " T5Encoding ReEncodeFont " 
bchbo8v VnCharterBT-Bold " 0.194 SlantFont T5Encoding ReEncodeFont " 
bchb8r CharterBT-Bold " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " 
bchbi8r CharterBT-BoldItalic " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " 
bchbo8r CharterBT-Bold " .167 SlantFont TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " 
bchr8r CharterBT-Roman " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " 
bchri8r CharterBT-Italic " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " 
bchro8r CharterBT-Roman " .167 SlantFont TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont "
```

If there would be a list on the internet, I guess it could be found by using a search engine and typing in five or more already known shorthands all together.

Comment: had some trouble to get this working, but eventually it did! thanks

Comment: However, there are a few MetaFont fonts without a font map line.

Comment: Also fonts installed as truetype are/should be missing a font map line because they can only be used with pdftex. (So usually style files should add the map when called rather than by default. This ensures they are only added for pdftex.) At least, this is what the convered gtamacfonts used to do.

Answer (score 6):

This shorthand naming scheme is called the [Berry naming scheme](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-fontname#%5BQ-fontname%5D). More information on it and a lot of font names can be found in [**Fontname**](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/fontname/fontname.pdf).

There is a more recent question of outstanding quality which can help with many problems regarding font usage: [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document)