# How to change fonts

Tags: fonts, packages

I'm sure this is a newbie question, but I can't figure this out.
I have tried to follow the advice here:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts
and here:
http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rf10/pstex/latexcommands.htm

But I can not seem to be able to generate any font change. I either get no change or error messages.

Here is the output of one failed attempt to change the font to Times using this command:

```
\rmfamily
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
```

http://pastebin.com/LJ62uC12

Apparently I either don't have a correct package installed or...

The output says " Metric (TFM) file not found." but I am not sure where to go from there.

Comment: If you want to use Times you can load one of the several packages, for example `mathptmx`, `newtx`  (using `\usepackage{newtxtext}` for text and `\usepackage{newtxmath}` for math). Your example should work (to see the effect use `\rmfamily` after the other instruction`. The problem could be a broken installation (and by the way you have an old one: 2009, you might consider to upgrade to a more recent one).

Comment: In my TeXLive installation the `tfm` file is found at `texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/times/ptmr7t.tfm`. That you should have the `fd` without the `tfm` seems like a broken install to me. I suggest to make a fresh install of a current TeXLive distribution.

Comment: Partial duplicate of [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/250119)

Answer (score 8):

Most of the time, it's advised to load the fonts you want beforehand by loading packages. A list of packages available in most TeX distributions can be found online in [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).

Packages will define `\rmdefault` (roman), `\sfdefault` (sans-serif) or `\ttdefault` (monospaced). For example:

```
\usepackage{tgheros,tgtermes,tgcursor}
```

Will set *TeX Gyre Termes* as the roman font, *TeX Gyre Heros* as the sans-serif font and *TeX Gyre Cursor* as the monospaced font.

XeTeX/LuaTeX users can also change the font families using the `fontspec` package: using `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont` or `\setmonofont` respectively.

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
```

One can change the default font family with:

```
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

However, sometimes one wishes to specify a font directly, with `fontspec` this is also quite easy:

```
\fontspec{TeX Gyre Heros}
```

For Type 1 fonts this is a bit more difficult:

```
\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont
```

More information about font names can be found in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12887/is-there-a-list-available-for-all-tex-fonts).

Comment: sorry about `http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rf10/pstex/latexcommands.htm` it’s ~=14 years old, put there for some now-forgotten discussion.  i shall add a heading saying that it is unreliable in current tex distros.