# Font selection in LaTeX article

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88192/how-to-change-fonts)

I'm a complete newbie to `LaTeX` and I'm writing a little `article`. Now, here's the question: how can I change the font I write with? ... I mean, something like what I used to do in `Microsoft Word`

Comment: For your first steps use Latin Modern with `\usepackage{lmodern}`. Have you read a short introduction to LaTeX? There you should find everything you need to start ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please always make sure to search for your problem first. Often the same question already exists.