# How to type Hindi words in LaTeX

Tags: languages

I am writing a thesis and have to write some Hindi words using LaTeX. When I use

```
\usepackage{devanagari} 
 removed. For example: 
{\dn school}
```

the output generated is

[image: output of the above code]

I want output to be like this: स्कूल

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 8):

You are probably not using the right Roman characters for the transliteration to work. As far as I have been able to figure out, in order to write "स्कूल" you would have to enter `{\dn-\8{k}l}` .

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\begin{document}
{\dn -\8{k}l}
\end{document}
```

outputs स्कूल. Make sure you get the capitalisation right.

This [link](https://cto.me.uk/posts/using-devanagari-in-latex/) might be of further help.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [Overleaf docs](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multilingual_typesetting_on_Overleaf_using_babel_and_fontspec)

```latex
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English as the main language
\babelprovide[import]{hindi}
\babelprovide[import]{sanskrit}
%\babelfont[*devanagari]{rm}{Lohit Devanagari}
\babelfont[*devanagari]{rm}{BABEL Unicode}
...


Hindi: \foreignlanguage{hindi}{हिन्दी}
Sanskrit: \foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{संस्कृतम्}
```

We have to use XeLaTex engine instead of PdfLatex.

[Here are some font options](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions%2FWhich_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F#Hindi_.28Devanagari_script.29)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using unicode.

I use `XeLaTeX` with unicode source to produce multilingual documents with latex. It has the advantage of having the native characters in your source.

You'll need to change to using `polyglossia`, rather than `babel`, if you move in this direction.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\begin{document}
{\dn skuula}
\end{document}
```

compile it using "devnag" compiler 
Results in following:

```
{\dn -\8{k}l}
```

and then run the generated ".tex" file in latex you will get the output required.

output:

```
स्कूल
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but it could use an updated answer.  LuaLaTeX can automatically detect which language you’re typing in, and change the font:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{hindi}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX,
                      Renderer=HarfBuzz }
\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common, Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[hindi]{rm}
          {Shobhika}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont{tt}
          {Libertinus Mono}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}
... removed, for example: स्कूल.
Neat!
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus/Shobhika sample]

In XeLaTeX, you can type in Devanagari with the (buggy) package `ucharclasses`:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}

\babelprovide[import]{hindi}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX }
\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common, Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[hindi]{rm}
          {Shobhika}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont{tt}
          {Libertinus Mono}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\setDefaultTransitions{\selectlanguage{english}}{}
\setTransitionsFor{Devanagari}{\selectlanguage{hindi}}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\setTransitionsFor{DevanagariExtended}{\selectlanguage{hindi}}{\selectlanguage{english}}

\begin{document}
... removed, for example: स्कूल.
Neat!
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus/Shobhika sample]

You’ve already gotten several solutions for PDFTeX. Another one is to [compile a word or short phrase as a standalone PDF and include it in your PDFTeX document.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549310/61644)  This allows you to embed a Unicode font that you can search and copy.

Answer (score 1):

Improving on Manjunath's answer.

For example, I wanted to type disha.

1. Create a temporary document named `temp.dn` with the following contents

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{devanagari}
   \begin{document}
   {\dn di"saa}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Depending on the word you want, try out some mapping from the document below. Save `temp.dn`
   https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2SIfLcmTaRuX3lfWm5RZ2QyUzA&usp=sharing
3. `devnag temp.dn`
4. Above command produces `temp.tex`
5. `pdflatex temp.tex`
6. Above command generates a pdf.
7. Check if the pdf has the hindi word that you wanted.
8. Once you arrive at the word that you wanted, look at `temp.tex` file
9. You will see `{\dn EdfA}`
10. Copy this piece of code to your original tex file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many methods but most of them fail because of the custom `\documentclass` that I was using (ACM paper format). I did a little ablation and found out that `\documentclass` was the issue. So the thing that worked for me (on Overleaf) was:

1. Use XeLaTeX (by clicking on "Menu")
2. Use `\newenvironment{myhindi}{\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Devanagari}\setmainfont{Lohit Devanagari}}{\par}`
3. Then `\begin{myhindi} अगर बच्चे का स्कूल \end{myhindi}`

And now you can just copy-paste whatever Hindi text you like.

If you are not able to use bold or italics non-Hindi text because of this method, then use `\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}` above the `newenvironment` command.

DISCLAIMER: Editing Hindi text in Overleaf editor is very difficult. So open a notepad from which you can edit and copy-paste.

reference: [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/hindi-project-template/vkcmcwjmwhbr), [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11539/change-font-in-a-single-paragraph)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.