# Switching between three scripts using `ucharclasses` does not seem to work

Tags: xetex, unicode, ucharclasses, tamil, devanagari

I wish to switch between three scripts, using `ucharclasses`. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[Latin,Tamil,Devanagari]{ucharclasses}
\setmainfont[Script=Latin]{Noto Serif}
\setmonofont{Noto Mono}
\newfontfamily\tamilfont[Script=Tamil,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Sans Tamil}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Sans Devanagari}
\setTransitionTo{Tamil}{\tamilfont}
\setTransitionFrom{Tamil}{\normalfont}
\setTransitionTo{Devanagari}{\devanagarifont}
\setTransitionFrom{Devanagari}{\normalfont}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
Using \texttt{ucharclasses}. This is the normal font. இது தமிழ் எழுத்து. इति देवनागरी लिपि. Back to English using the Latin script.

\medskip

Declaring fonts explicitly. This is the normal font. {\tamilfont இது தமிழ் எழுத்து.} {\devanagarifont इति देवनागरी लिपि.} Back to English using the Latin script.
\end{document}
```

I wish to avoid explicit font declarations if I can, and use the `ucharclasses` package instead. But I have read that it is buggy.

Can someone suggest a workaround, if there is one, for switching between three scripts, using `ucharclasses` please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often simpler to set up the ucharclass commands yourself as the package versions are not always clear which commands will run at the boundary, however in this case, this seems to work, I added colour to help identify the scripts (which I can't read)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,color}
\usepackage[Latin,Tamil,Devanagari]{ucharclasses}
\setmainfont[Script=Latin]{Noto Serif}
\setmonofont{Noto Mono}
\newfontfamily\tamilfont[Script=Tamil,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Sans Tamil}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Sans Devanagari}

\setTransitionsForLatin{\normalfont\color{blue}}{}
\setTransitionTo{Tamil}{\tamilfont\color{red}}
\setTransitionsForDevanagari{\devanagarifont\color{green}}{}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\color{blue}
Using \texttt{ucharclasses}. This is the normal font. இது தமிழ் எழுத்து. इति देवनागरी लिपि. Back to English using the Latin script.

\medskip
\color{blue}

Declaring fonts explicitly. This is the normal font. {\tamilfont\color{red} இது தமிழ் எழுத்து.} {\devanagarifont\color{green} इति देवनागरी लिपि.} Back to English using the Latin script.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @David Carlisle. It works!

I have three questions:

(1)  Although `Devanagari` is not mentioned in the "informal groups" of the documentation, `\setTransitionsForDevanagari` works but `\setTransitionsForTamil` does not. Why?

(2) Does `\setTransitionsForDevanagari` perform the functions of both `\setTransitionToDevanagari` and `\setTransitionFromDevanagari`?

(3) Is there another package, apart from `ucharclasses` that performs a similar or identical function?

Comment: @chandra I have no idea why the package authors didn't define `For` versions for all classes, as I say the behaviour of the package at the boundaries is very hard to follow with so many declaration forms exactly which commands run as you switch from one class to another is hard to follow,. If it works it works but when it doesn't it's easier to use teh xetex ucharclass primitives directly to specify the commands to run at each transition.

Comment: It appears that `\setTransitionsForLatin{\normalfont}{}` clobbers emphasized text such as `\textit{English}`. So, it might be better to go the `lualatex` way and eschew `ucharclasses` entirely, unless there is a simple workaround for this too.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in using lualatex.

Adapting @Davislor's answer at [How to type Hindi words in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199773/how-to-type-hindi-words-in-latex/) ("LuaLaTeX can automatically detect which language you’re typing in, and change the font:"),

[image: using lualtex]

MWE

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}

\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{hindi}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{tamil}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX,
                      Renderer=HarfBuzz }
\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common, Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[hindi]{rm}[Color=blue]
          {Shobhika}
\babelfont[tamil]{rm}[Color=red]
          {Noto Sans Tamil}          

\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont{tt}
          {Libertinus Mono}

\begin{document}

This is the normal font. இது தமிழ் எழுத்து. इति देवनागरी लिपि. Back to English using the Latin script.

स्कूल: 

{\large இந்தி }

(Hindi, இந்தி: हिन्दी, நவீன தரநிலை இந்தி: मानक हिन्दी) அல்லது ஹிந்தி இந்தியாவின் வட மாநிலங்களில் பெரும்பான்மையாகப் பேசப்படும் மொழியாகும்.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Cicada. I was not aware of the recent developments in `lualatex` and `babel` and also for the link. I shall try them out. It helps to have an alternative means to accomplish multi-script typesetting so that there is a fallback option.