# Hindi/devanagari font for pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, overleaf, arxiv

How can I include Hindi font in PDFlatex/latex? I need to upload the source in arxiv, so can't compile it with XeLaTex/lualatex. Please don't suggest fontspec package because it is not compatible with pdflatex.

Comment: See, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199773/how-to-type-hindi-words-in-latex/ .

Comment: How much hindi will be in your text? Only a few words or is it the main language?

Comment: I'll needing few words only

Comment: the link worked. Thanks!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, unrelated to OP's question; but if they had said they need Devanagari script as the main language; what would have been a possible solution? Is there any internal Unicode to METAFONT converter for Devanagari?

Comment: Voting to close, because a link to an earlier question in a comment solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

arXiv doesn't support compilation in XeLaTeX or LuaTeX, so you'll need to contact help@arxiv.org for more information as to how to proceed.